# Stepping over an item in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array such which lists a number of options for a menu and then in each of those options another array of suboptions.

In one display I want to check the key of one of the top options i.e 'useroptions' and if I find that, I want to skip over that whole subarray and move onto the next one.  I'm having a problem at the moment though  I have this code, but it shows the last suboption

```
if($item->key=='useroptions' {
    $item = $item->children->last();
}
```

I would have thought something like

```
$item = $item->sibling->next();
```

but this isn't working..  Can anyone show me the correct way please.

Thanks

Wheelz

Comment: check my answer,i gave you two examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($item->key != 'useroptions') {
   // Do something using subarray
}
```

Comment: when posting answers please try to put in an explanation of any code posted not just post code no its own.

Comment: Use this code below the first array and then write the subarray code inside this condition. This condition will check whether the condition is true or not. If true then it will not execute the whole subarray code.
 I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    switch($value) {

        case 3:
            echo '&lt;p&gt;Skipped the number 3&lt;/p&gt;';
            break 1;
        default:
break;
}
}
?&gt;
```

Or this one:

```
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    if ( $value == 3 )
        continue; # Skips

    # Code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function next() to advance to the next pointer in array.

```
next($array)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

Answer (score 0):

if that if is inside a loop then do this it might help :

```
if($item->key=='useroptions') {
   continue;
}
```